# Difference between a wildcard certificate and a multi domain certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, wildcard

I have a multidomain certificate that supports the following types of domains

```
abc.myComany.com
123.myCompany.com
xyz.myCompany.com
```

I now need it to support `mysubdomain.myComany.com` From reading various online post it seems like I need a wildcard certificate for `"*.myComapny.com"` But if this isnt a possibility , can I add `mysubdomain.myCompany.com`' as another supported domain to the multidomain certificate? Will this work?

Comment: The difference is obvious, you've already stated it.  A multi-domain certificate can be used for multiple domains.  A wildcard certificate can be used for all subdomains of the domain it's a wildcard for.  Whether you can add an additional subdomain to your multi-domain certificate is a question for your certificate vendor.  They're the one that makes the rules.  Technically, there's no reason you can't add another.

Comment: It will definitely work. For this case, wildcard makes more sense, but multidomain certificate for 3-4 domains would be cheaper and you could add another domain as well. Max number of certificates on multidomain cerrtificate is limited depending on ssl suplier. Also, above certain number of domains, multidomain certificate becomes more expensive than wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add a comment.  One gotcha I ran into is that the wildcard *.contoso.com will not work for dc1.domain.forest.contoso.com.  I was not allowed to use the wildcard on any level above (below?) the level that the * is at.  So if you need to say verify adfs.contoso.com and adfs-server.domain.forest.contoso.com you would need the multi domain certificate as opposed to the wildcard certificate.